# hover: display not showing a div

Tags: html, css, hover

I write this code: jsfiddle.net/4ror198u/1/

That zombi class is ok and when my mouse goes over it it show me that pink box, but why when my mouse is over blue i canno't see the green class ?
Can you help me where im wrong and what i need to do to fix this problem, also to suggest some examples why this thing hapening and how to prevent it in feature.
Thanx in advance! :)

Comment: Are those JS comment dude?

Comment: I wana use only HTML and CSS. No js. I cnow it can be done with js but i dont wana to use it. I just wana answer why my green div didnt show up over the blue one when mouse is over it ( over the blue one ).

Comment: You have a hover psuedo class on `.playerCover`, but you didn't apply that class to any of the elements.  So, green will never show because you never used `.playerCover`

Comment: @Smeegs Even after edit there still not showing up :/

https://jsfiddle.net/4ror198u/1/

Comment: You still didn't use the class.  Instead of playercover, use shell.  Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4ror198u/2/

Comment: Is it there a way to use blue insted of shell to show my green div ? Also can you tell me why need to write shell instead of blue to make things work ?

Answer (score 0):

You have misplaced the class green with class shell so I rearranged that and I placed some attributes to the .green class in order the difference to be obvious.The blue box works exactly as the effect that you have for the zombieone.

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>

<style>

    * {
        color: yellow;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .zombitwo {
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        background: pink;
        border-radius: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 200px;
        display: none;

    }

    .zombione:hover + .zombitwo {
        display: block;
    }

    .black{
    //border: 5px solid red;
        background-color: black;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;

    }

    .blue{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: blue;
    //border: 5px solid blue;
    }

    .green{

        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: green;
        color:red;
    //border: 5px solid green;
        display: none;
        text-align:center;

    }

    .blue:hover + .green{
        display: block;
    }

</style>
```

```
<div class="zombione">test</div>
<div class="zombitwo">work</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="shell">
        <div class="black">
            <div class="blue">
                <div class="shell">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="green">
                <div class="shell">
                    <div class="sblack"></div>
                    <div class="sred"></div>
                    <div class="sgreen">It works fine!!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```